# Joomla-links don't work

Tags: joomla, hyperlink

I have two sites

http://buildingindustry.org/

and his copy on

http://beauty-industry.org

The last was restored from backup of first site. Links on second site don't work. What could be happen with second site ?

Thanks.

Comment: getting "Notice" notifications,  you can off it from admin panel. Site->Global Configuration->Server->Error Reporting.

Comment: If the links are full links and not relative paths, perhaps there is a difference in the file structure of the 2nd server?

Answer (score 1):

Try to flush/clear the cache and any entries in the redirect extension. Should do the trick.
If you're using any SEF-component, don't forget to delete the cache here as well.